# Who, why and when to say the prayer of Rabbi Nechuniyoh ben Hakoneh?

Tags: prayer-book, shemos-sacred-names, provenance

The prayer [אָנָּא בְּכֹחַ](https://daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=3311) is ascribed to Rabbi Nechuniyoh ben Hakoneh and appears in the section of the daily sacrifices, before Lecho Dodi in Kabbolas Shabbos and at other points.

According to the mekubolim, it hints at the 42-letter name of G-d and it therefore ends with
"ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד" . The  42-letter name of G-d is given over only to elevated people (Kiddushin 71a).

> אמר רבי יהודה אמר רב, שם של מ"ב אותיון אין מוסרין אותו אלא למי שצנוע
> ועניו ועומד בחצי ימיו ואינו כועס ואינו משתכר ואינו מעמיד על מדותיו.
>
> Rabbi Yehudah said in the name of Rav, the 42-letter name of G-d is
> passed over only to humble and modest people, over 35 years old, who
> neither get angry, over-indulge or insist on their dues.

This extract of the translation gives the flavour of the prayer:

> Please, by the force of Your great right hand, release the bound one.
> Accept the prayer of Your people; strengthen us, purify us, Awesome
> One! Please! Mighty One, those who seek Your Unity, preserve them like
> the pupil [of Your eye].

I have two questions:

Why does it appear in the daily sacrifices and before Lecho Dodi?

Should everyone say it or only specially refined people?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana_b%27Koach#:~:text=Ana%20b'Koach%20(Hebrew%3A,Omer%20which%20lasts%20seven%20weeks.

Comment: It was originally composed as a *yichud*.

Comment: What's a yichud?